# SWIFT - Downcast an array to a string

Tags: arrays, swift, downcast

```
@IBOutlet var cityField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var message: UILabel!

@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

   self.view.endEditing(true)       
   var urlString = "http://www.weather-forecast.com/locations/" + cityField.text.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "") + "/forecasts/latest"

    var url = NSURL(string: urlString)        
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) {(data, respons, error) in         
        var urlContent =  NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)            
        var contentArray = urlContent.componentsSeparatedByString("<span class=\"phrase\">")            
        var newContentArray = contentArray[1].componentsSeparatedByString("</span>")

        self.message.text = newContentArray[0] as? String            
        println(urlString)
    }        
    task.resume()        
}
```

Here is a simple weather app i'm making, my problem is when i click the button it doesn't really show the weather and it gives me this error "fatal error: Array index out of range"
Help, please.

Comment: What does `println(newContentArray.count)` gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line:

```
    var newContentArray = contentArray[1].componentsSeparatedByString("</span>")
```

You assume that `contentArray` will have at least two elements. If it doesn't, you will crash. Obviously that assumption is not correct. You cannot rely on data you receive from outside you app; you must validate that it's in the format you expect before processing it.

Comment: i got that from the page source, do i need to double check that again ?

Comment: You cannot guarantee the format of a page you fetch from the network. Especially if you're parsing HTML, they could change at any time (it's not even an API). It is not acceptable behavior to crash just because a website sent you data you didn't expect.

Comment: I know that i have to use an API if i'm going to make a useful reliable app, i was just experimenting with this one, and i thought the problem maws with the syntaxes itself.
It works fine now after some changes, but results take too long to show on both simulator and my phone, but shows instantly in console.

Comment: Even when you're using an API, you need to check that you get back what you expected. Your app should be willing to accept total garbage from the server without crashing.

Comment: Good tip, thnx for your help Rob.